# Using Euler's method to estimate a value of y(1.1) if y(1,0) = 0.

Tags: eulers-method

I am currently attempting some past paper exam questions and have come across a question on Euler's method that I am unsure on how to solve.

This is the question;

MCQ on Euler's Method:
[image]

I have had an attempt, however, what I am most confused on is all the examples I can find online all have a value of x that is increasing.

In this example from the coordinated given in y(1,0) and y(1,1) I believe x is constantly at 1? Because of this I am unsure of how to answer this.

I am hoping someone could explain to me what I might have missed in understanding this question? Or how I can extract the right information that I need so I can solve it!

Many thanks,

Liam

Comment: You are given $y(1)$ and asked to find $y(1.1)$. I am confused about what you are saying. That is just a step in the Euler Method.

Comment: @Moo Oh wow, it's y(1.0) not y(1,0), I misread the question. So sorry clearly i need a break! Thank you very much!